# Application getInstance returning null

Tags: android, singleton

I'm facing a problem that i can figure it out.

My Application

```
public class AppApplication extends Application {

    public static AppApplication sInstance;

    public static User mUser;

    public static AppApplication getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

        sInstance = this;
        mUser = restoreUserFromSession();

        ReportUtils.getsInstance(this).resendCachedReport();

    }
    /**
     * Restore logged user stored on session
     * @return
     */
    public User restoreUserFromSession(){
        return UserSession.getInstance(this).restoreUser();
    }
}
```

My Manifest

```
<application
        android:name=".AppApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
.
.
.
</application>
```

In my Fragment I have that functino

```
public void doLogin(RestParams params) {
        RestClient.getApi(getActivity(), getActivity()).doLogin(params.getParams(), new RestCallback<LoginApi>() {
            @Override
            public void failure(RestError restError) {
                hideProgress();
                LOGI(TAG, restError.getStrMessage());
                DialogUtils.getInstance().showOkDialog(getActivity(),
                        getString(R.string.str_warning),
                        restError.getStrMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void successApi(final LoginApi loginApi, Response response) {
                loginApi.data.email = mEditEmail.getText().toString();

                if(AppApplication.getInstance() != null) {
                    AppApplication.getInstance().saveUserSession(loginApi.data);
                } else {
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            AppApplication.getInstance().saveUserSession(loginApi.data);
                            LogUtils.setCrashUser(loginApi.data.name);
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
                mListener.goToMain();

                GcmUtils gcm = new GcmUtils(getActivity(), getActivity());
                gcm.registerInBackground();
            }
        });
    }
```

And my problem is when I launch the app for the fist time, the AppApplication.getInstance() return null, when I open the app again, every thing works fine, I have no idea what is wrong.

**----EDITED----**

My problem is that the first time the Activity's onCreate is called before Application's onCreate, that happens only in Nexus 9 - API 23 so far.

Obs: When I run in debug mode, it does not happen

Comment: please `Toast` out `String.valueOf(sInstance==null)` inside method `getInstance` before returning `sInstance` and tell me what you get

Comment: try using [getApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29) method in your activity

Comment: @ElvisChweya I can't call a toast from getInstance, because is a static method and the toast need a context and I don't have one, but, with Log.i i got: 02-20 18:51:55.697 26900-26900/? I/AppApplication: true, and when the app crash, I open it again and it returns 02-20 18:52:16.364 27202-27202/? I/AppApplication: false

Comment: I meet same issue , has you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

try initialising sInstance from activity that mean calling some method of application class and init in it

You are getting first time null as application is not initialized, and you tried to call it before

Comment: This is not gonna work. `sInstance` variable is static. Cannot reference `this` from static context. Java fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment use this:

```
(AppApplication) getActivity().getApplication()
```

to access your application instance.

Example:

```
((AppApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).saveUserSession(loginApi.data);
```